# Using launchSettings.json when the WebAPI is in a separate assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I am going for Clean Architecture where I try to split my Host setup from my Web Application.

My intention is that my Host assembly declares a basic Host and configures my domain.
Then from separate assemblies I register left-side-adapters, like the WebApi.

I have a running solution that works. The only special consideration, was regarding `AddControllers()`, where I had to instruct it to look outside the Entry assembly.

But, my solution ignores my launchSettings.json completely.
Normaly behvavior is that my Kestrel server will see an empty Kestrel configuration and then instead load the settings from `properties/launchSettings.json`

This does not happen, when I declare my WebApi in a separate assembly.

Any tips on what I need to change, so my WebApi assembly will load the `properties/launchSettings.json` from inside my Host assembly?

Assembly: **Host**

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
           ...
        });

        builder.ConfigureWebApi();

        var app = builder.Build();
        await app.RunAsServiceAsync();
    }
}
```

Assembly **WebApi**

```
public static class StartupExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureWebApi(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services
                    .AddControllers()
                    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
// Adding this to enable loading controllers from my WebAPI assembly
                    .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
                services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
                services.AddSwaggerGen();
            });

            webBuilder.Configure((context, app) =>
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Kestrel": {}
}
```

Comment: Can you use builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile in your startup file?

Comment: Adding `.AddJsonFile(@"Properties\launchSettings.json")` has no effect.
I am also under the impression that it is Visual Studio that uses the file and not the .Net Framework.